# Why does emacs (for windows) change the encoding of xml files from utf-16 little endian to utf-16 big endian?

Tags: xml, powershell, encoding, emacs, utf-16

Why does Emacs for Windows change the encoding of a unicode (utf-16le) xml file to utf-16be without telling me after saving?  You can mouse over the U in the lower left to see the encoding, left click for more info.  Exported xml files from Task Scheduler are typically like this.  Example xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<hi />
```

If I load and save it in powershell, it goes back to utf-16 le (both in windows and osx).

```
[xml]$xml = get-content test.xml
$xml.save('test.xml')
```

Worse, you lose the bom with this setting and the file is ruined until I open it in Notepad and save it again.  UTF-16LE is a valid IANA character set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16LE"?>
<hi />
```

EDIT:

Apparently the encoding is directed by the encoding= tag in emacs xml mode or nxml mode.  There's a patch in to change the behavior in a future emacs version.  If it's already utf16 le with a bom, it will stay that way.

Comment: trying to get under interesting tab

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to pop up in the interesting tab when I edit it.